# Zero sized array in struct managed by shared pointer

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr

Consider the following structure:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double arr[0];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

As you can see, this structure is packed and has Zero sized array at the end.
I'd like to send this as binary data over the network (assume I took care of endianity).

In C/C++ I could just use malloc to allocate as much space as I want and use free later.

I'd like this memory to be handled by std::shared_ptr.

Is there a straight forward way of doing so without special hacks?

Comment: C++ does not allow zero sized arrays.

Comment: This looks like a C programming trick called an extensible array. If your compiler extends the C++ Standard and allows them, they will likely follow the C Language rules. If the compiler does not support them, you will have to do your own serialization.

Comment: Note that C and C++ are different languages and grow more different with every revision of either's Standard.

Comment: _"In C/C++ I could just use malloc_" ... In C++ you'll _extremely_ rarely use `malloc`.

Comment: Don't use `__attribute__((packed))`. It forces the compiler to generate horrible code for most architectures. You are better of writing code to copy the members individually from/to a buffer.

Comment: gcc and clang do allow using zero sized array in C++. Don't know/care about VS/other compilers. This structure represents data going over the network, hence the packed attribute. I know the compiler generates crappy code for it, but this is for serialization purposes only. Internally in my application, there's another structure for real use (serialize/deserealize from it). And I agree regarding the malloc in C++. I almost never use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like this memory to be handled by std::shared_ptr.
>
> Is there a straight forward way of doing so without special hacks?

Sure, there is:

```
shared_ptr<S> make_buffer(size_t s)
{
    auto buffer = malloc(s);                    // allocate as usual
    auto release = [](void* p) { free(p); };    // a deleter
    shared_ptr<void> sptr(buffer, release);     // make it shared
    return { sptr, new(buffer) S };             // an aliased pointer
}
```

This works with any objects that are placed in a malloced buffer, not just when there are zero-sized arrays, provided that the destructor is trivial (performs no action) because it is never called.

The usual caveats about zero-sized arrays and packed structures still apply as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     double arr[0];
> } __attribute__((packed));
> ```

Zero sized arrays are not allowed as data members (nor as any other variable) in C++. Furthermore, there is no such attribute as `packed` in C++; it is a language extension (as such, it may be considered to be a special hack). `__attribute__` itself is a language extension. The standard syntax for function attributes uses nested square brackets like this: `[[example_attribute]]`.

> I'd like to send this as binary data over the network

You probably should properly serialise the data. There are many serialisation specifications although none of them is universally ubiquitous and none of them is implemented in the C++ standard library. Indeed, there isn't a standard API for network commnication either.

A straightforward solution is to pick an existing serialisation format and use an existing library that implements it.

Comment: This packed structure is used for serialization/deserialisation and nothing else. It's just easier for me to convey to other users this way the packet structure over the network. __attribute__ ((packed)), which I know is a compiler extension is supported by clang and gcc in c++, which are the only compilers I care about.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me explain again why I have this packed structure:
it is used for serialization of data over the network so there's a header file with all network packet structures.

I know it generates bad assembly due to alignment issues, but I guess that this problem persists with regular serialization (copy to char * buffer with memcpy).

Zero size arrays are supported both by gcc and clang which I use.

Here's an example of a full program with a solution to my question and it's output (same output for gcc and g++).
compiled with -O3 -std=c++17 flags

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

struct S1
{
    ~S1() {std::cout << "deleting s1" << std::endl;}
    char a;
    int b;
    int c[0];
} __attribute__((packed));

struct S2
{
    char a;
    int b;
    int c[0];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto s1 = std::shared_ptr<S1>(static_cast<S1 *>(::operator 
              new(sizeof(S1) + sizeof(int) * 1e6)));

    std::cout << "is standart: " << std::is_standard_layout<S1>::value << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i)
    {
        s1->c[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << sizeof(S1) << ", " << sizeof(S2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << offsetof(S1, c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << offsetof(S2, c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
is standart: 1
5, 8
5
8
deleting s1
```

Is there anything wrong with doing this?
I made sure using valgrind all allocations/frees work properly.

Comment: This appears to be a new question rather than an answer. If it's a new question, I recommend opening up a new question and deleting this not-yet answer. If things turn out well, update this to be a real answer and undelete it. It it is intended as an answer reword it so that it does not read like a question.